# Using compass with yeoman

Tags: compass-sass, yeoman

I have installed yeoman, and after running `yeoman server`

I get the following error

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
<FATAL> You need to have Compass installed. </FATAL>
```

How do install compass and get it to work with yeoman?  I am using a mac (mountain lion) and have tried `yeoman install compass` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are instructions on [how to install Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/) on the Compass website.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just do it like Compass Page says, and after that, you can work with the yeoman without problems.

1. gem update --system
2. gem install compass